# TK Tablelist Advise

Tags: tcl

I'm a newbie to tk tablelist. I would like to create an application in Linux that able to read a text file and tabulate contents to table format. I able to complete the task with tablelist.

In addition, I woukd need to include a function where user able to select a row in the table, and insert a new row into the table by shift the selected row downward(similar to insert function in excel). May I know how can I do it with tablelist ? Please advise, thanks !

Comment: Could you explain what is the exact problem you found in inserting a new row?

Comment: My problem is I do not know how to do it and I couldn't find any example from Internet. My idea is user select a row on the table -> click a button (e.g. Insert or add), a new row will be added into the table at selected location by shifting down all other rows. The new row should be an empty row where user can add new data into the cells. And, user can output whole table into a text file. May I know is it feasible to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to solved the problem by using : curselection to determine selected line and insert to add new row.